# Apply after with arguments

Tags: functional-style

Though I have been using Mathematica on and off for many years to help with learning math, it is only recently I have been introduced to its functional programming style and power. So for example if I have a list

```
Table[k, {k, 1, 4}]
```

then I can do

```
Times @@ Table[k, {k, 1, 4}]
```

to get its product. But one of my favourites is the 'apply after'. For example:

```
( {
 {Cosh[z], Sinh[z]},
 {Sinh[z], Cosh[z]}
  } ) - λ*IdentityMatrix[2]
```

will give me

```
{{-λ + Cosh[z], Sinh[z]}, {Sinh[z], -λ + Cosh[z]}}
```

(of course it looks much nice in free-form input) and I can see the matrix structure. But now once I see the matrix, I can go to the same input line and append a `//Det` to compute its determinant.

My question is at this point, is there a way to do "apply after" *with* arguments? For example can I go to the output line after computing the determinant and append something along the lines of,

```
λ^2 - 2 λ Cosh[z] + Cosh[z]^2 - Sinh[z]^2 == 0 // 
 Solve[#, λ]
```

To solve for lambda?

Basically I guess I want to pipe the output/expression into a certain place in a function call. Yes I know I can do

```
Solve[% == 0, λ]
```

on the next line but I was just curious.

Comment: add `&` , that is , use `λ^2 - 2 λ Cosh[z] + Cosh[z]^2 - Sinh[z]^2 == 0 // 
    Solve[#, λ] &`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
λ^2 - 2 λ Cosh[z] + Cosh[z]^2 - Sinh[z]^2 == 0 // Solve[#, λ] &
λ^2 - 2 λ Cosh[z] + Cosh[z]^2 - Sinh[z]^2 == 0 // Function[Solve[#, λ]]
λ^2 - 2 λ Cosh[z] + Cosh[z]^2 - Sinh[z]^2 == 0    // Function[{x}, Solve[x,  λ]]
```

all give

> {{λ -> Cosh[z] - Sinh[z]}, {λ -> Cosh[z] + Sinh[z]}}

For the case in comments below:

```
({{Cosh@z, Sinh@z}, {Sinh@z, Cosh@z}} - λ IdentityMatrix[2] // Det)==0 // Solve[#, λ] &
```

> {{λ -> Cosh[z] - Sinh[z]}, {λ -> Cosh[z] + Sinh[z]}}

Comment: I guess that works. I would have never guessed this...though we have to use parenthesis to apply after twice...

(( {
       {Cosh[z], Sinh[z]},
       {Sinh[z], Cosh[z]}
      } ) - \[Lambda]*IdentityMatrix[2] // Det) == 0 // 
 Solve[#, \[Lambda]] &

But I can live with that.

Comment: @ITA, you don't need the inner parentheses. Thank you for the accept.